# Cycling through a list with async call inside

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of Ids, I need to iterate through all the Ids, and for each Ids of the array make an async call to retrieve a value from DB, then sums all the value gathered. I did something like this

```
  let quantity = 0;
  for (const id of [1,2,3,4]) {
    const subQuantity = await getSubQuantityById(id);
    quantity += subQuantity;
  }
```

Is there a more elegant and coincise way to write this for in javascript?

Comment: `(await Promise.all([1,2,3,4].map(i => getSubQuantityById(id))).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0)`

Comment: @Konrad Your solution will result in uncontrollable concurrency, which in the context of a database usually means trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't follow @vitaly-t's argument that concurrent database queries will cause "problems" - at least not when we are talking about simple queries and there is a "moderate" number of these queries.

Here is my version of doing the summation. Obviously, the `console.log` in the last `.then()` needs to be replaced by the actual action that needs to happen with the calculated result.

```js
// a placeholder function for testing:
function getSubQuantityById(i){
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+i).then(r=>r.json()).then(u=>+u.address.geo.lat);
}

Promise.all([1,2,3,4].map(id => getSubQuantityById(id)))
 .then(d=>d.reduce((p, c) => p + c,0))
 .then(console.log)
```

Comment: To explain... when the number of queries significantly exceeds the size of the database pool available, it clogs the pool, and cripples the performance. One needs to leverage the number of concurrent queries that fits into the size of the available connection pool, or else the performance of such app will dive nose-down. I'm also the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), so I know such things for sure.

Comment: Thanks @Vitaly-t for explaining these details - very helpful. Yes, for these situations it is certainly a good idea to keep the requests sequential.

Comment: Sort of, if you have a small connection pool, like on some cheap hostings. Otherwise, you'd want some small window of concurrency, like 10 requests at a time, and that's it. Best is to make it configurable.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally fine because your case include an `async` operation. Using a `forEach` instead is not possible here at all.

Your `for` loop is perfectly clean. If you want to make it shorter you could even do:

```
let totalQuantity = 0;
for (const id of arrayOfIds) {
  totalQuantity += await getSubQuantityById(id);
}
```

As-is, it may even be more clear than using `+= await` as above.

Naming could be improved as suggested.

I find the following one liner suggested in comments more cryptic/dirty:

```
(await Promise.all([1,2,3,4].map(i => getSubQuantityById(id))).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0)
```

Edit: Props to @vitaly-t, who indicates that using Promise.all the way this one liner does will result in uncontrollable concurrency and lead to troubles in the context of a database

Comment: That one-liner will result in uncontrollable concurrency, which in the context of a database usually means trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more elegant and coincise way to write this for in javascript?

Certainly, by processing your input as an iterable. The solution below uses [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipeAsync, map, wait, reduce} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipeAsync(
    [1, 2, 3, 4], // your list of id-s
    map(getSubQuantityById), // remap ids into async requests
    wait(), // resolve requests
    reduce((a, c) => a + c) // calculate the sum
); //=> AsyncIterableExt<number>
```

Testing the iterable:

```
(async function () {
    console.log(await i.first); //=> the sum
})();
```

It is elegant, because you can inject more processing logic right into the iteration pipeline, and the code will remain very easy to read. Also, it is lazy-executing, initiates only when iterated.

Perhaps even more importantly, such a solution lets you control concurrency, to avoid producing too many requests against the database. And you can fine-tune concurrency, by replacing [wait](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/wait.html) with [waitRace](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/waitRace.html).

P.S. I'm the author of [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops).